# FCM Android - null message ID

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented my subclass of [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html) and I'm successfully receiving downstream messages in `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage)`. My problem is that `RemoteMessage.getMessageId()` always returns `null`. From what I understood, message ID is mandatory and should be automatically generated by the FCM server. In fact, calling `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`
 returns a message ID, I just cannot access it on the app side.

Is there something I am missing?

Here's my FCM messaging service class:

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FcmMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Logg.d(TAG, "Received message; id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Logg.d(TAG, "Data: " + data);

        String message = data.get("message");
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `FirebaseMessagingService` class?

Comment: It's just a basic minimal implementation, but here you go.

Comment: Okaay.. Sorry. I'm still looking around. I'm a little bit confused. Where did you find the *message ID is mandatory and should be automatically generated by the FCM server.*? Can you provide the sample messageId you're receiving when calling `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`? :)

Comment: This is what I got from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream . The request returns a proper downstream HTTP message response body JSON. Under `results` I'm getting a single item array like that: `[{"message_id":"0:1466752320691571%d81689fef9fd7ecd"}]`.

Comment: Oh wait. Are you sending via the Firebase Console or your own Server?

Comment: I have a server that sends messages using `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Comment: I see. Sorry. I was confused again in my end. Tried it out and also received a null value. I'll try to look around more.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**As of Firebase Android SDK 9.4 this issue has been resolved**

From the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

> **FIXED** `RemoteMessage#getMessageId()` now returns the correct message-id for received messages. Previously, it returned `null`.

Updating the `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` dependency to version `9.4.0` has indeed fixed the problem.

---

**Update 2.07.2016:** I was informed that this is indeed a bug and a fix will be included in the nearest release.

---

Turns out we cannot get message ID on the app side. I've asked the Firebase support for help and this is what they told me:

> When FCM has successfully receives the request, it will attempt to deliver to all subscribed devices, FCM will return a response which includes messageID to your server.
>   You cannot directly get MessageID on your client side (Android device). MessageID is a parameter in response payload.

As a workaround I am generating custom message identifiers on the server and passing them in the payload.

What RemoteMessage.getMessageId() actually does remains a mystery.

Comment: Six months later, no change, getMessageID still returns null, in direct opposition to the current documenation. Too bad, as that would have been very handy in having unique descriptors in the Intents to launch your app.

Comment: Actually it's been just a month (I'm European ;) ). Still, the bug has not been fixed since then. Hopefully it will be addressed in the next release.

Comment: This is very weird. The method `getMessageId()` works fine for my ASUS device, but returns `null`to my SAMSUNG device. I'm using the same code with 9.4.0 version.

Comment: Same here. It does not work with 9.8.0 on a Samsung GT-I8190 with android 4.1